# How to set attributes to area with own jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

i have a image that i need to give them several links on several places. so i decided to map the image. Unfortunately i have 12 links. So my idea was to create a jquery function that sets the attributes to the area.

my code:

```
<img src="pages/dn-01.jpg" usemap="index" class="map">
<map name="index">
<area id="T-Shirts">
<area id="Polos">
<area id="Sweats">
<area id="Sports&Outdoor">
<area id="Tradition">
<area id="Fleece">
<area id="Jackets&Vests">
<area id="Shirts&Business&Trousers">
<area id="Workwear&Safety">
<area id="Underwear&Baby&Towels">
<area id="Caps&Hats">
<area id="Bags&Umbrellas&Accessories">
</map>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#T-Shirts').attr({
        shape: 'rect',
        coords: '519,134,777,212',
        href: '#',
        alt: 'T-Shirts'
    });

    function addAtrribute(myID, param1, param2, param3, param4) {
        var ID = '#' + myID;
        $('ID').attr({
            shape: param1,
            coords: param2,
            href: param3,
            alt: param4
        }); 
    }
    addAtrribute('Polos', 'rect', '519,212,777,290','#','Polos');
})
</script>
```

what do i make wrong with the addAtribute function because it don't set the attributes to the id=Polo

thank you for your help

Comment: ID is a variable `$(ID)` instead of `$('ID')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put `ID` as **string** in selector, you need to put it a **variable** as below::

```
$(ID).attr({
            shape: param1,
            coords: param2,
            href: param3,
            alt: param4
        });
```

Comment: If it helped you please accept the answer and upvote it for helping others. :)

Comment: Do somebody know how can i hover the areas ?